What Is the Function of the Participle Clause in 'Time + -ing'?

[1] My time working in the US was eventful, to say the least.'

In Example 1, I have used a participial-gerund clause (or present participle clause, if you prefer) alongside the noun 'time,' and I'm wondering what its function is in the clause. We often talk about -ing relative clauses (or non-finite relative clauses), such as in 'the man sitting behind us' ('the man who is sitting behind us'), but all the examples I have seen position the subject as the standard noun phrase minus the participle clause.
There are other cases that resemble this, but I believe the -ing clause behaves differently, as a depictive adjunct. (See Example 2.)

[2] I spent a lot of time wondering about her.

Am I correct in assuming that the -ing clause in Example 1 is a rather unique type of 'reduced relative clause'? So, we could say, 'My time when I was working in the US was eventful, to say the least.' I further believe this may be true because other time-oriented phrases can be used similarly. (See Example 3.)

[3] My days helping you are over.


I've seen analyses where the clause is considered to have been reduced, but also have seen contemporary grammarians reject that analysis and say it's a type of clause in its own right.  I've added the grammar tag.

His bluff playing with word meanings was funny. No, it is not a reduced clause.

@Lambie That example sounds a little awkward to me, but it proves the point. Is it similar to a complement clause, like a declarative content clause ('that' clause) or infinitive clause? For example, 'The fact that he had changed made no difference to her.'

No, it isn't like those at all. It's a noun followed by a gerund (participial) clause. My time is often followed by an action verb: My time doing laundry was boring. To make it a reduced clause, you have to change it too much: My time [when I was] doing laundry was boring. That's overfiddling with it, imo.

However the syntax involved is analysed, semantically, 'My time working in the US was' = 'The time I spent working in the US was ...' and 'My days helping you are over' = 'The  days I spent helping you are over'. In contrast, 'I spent a lot of time wondering about her' = 'I spent a lot of time doing this: wondering about her.' The first two sentences ([1] & [3]) use the ing-clauses to restrict/characterise the noun (which time? which days?) while the other uses the ing-clause to say what 'I' spent a lot of time doing. Almost (if not?) a phase structure (I went dancing / he sat knitting).

According to CGEL (the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language), gerund-participials as modifier in noun phrases are not analyzed as relative clauses because there is no possibility of them containing a relative word or phrase (p.1265).

*Let me tell you about my time when working in the US.
*Let me tell you about my time that working in the US.

Gerund-participials as complements is never discussed, only to-infinitival complements in NPs (p.439, 1256-1264).
Several categories of nouns can have gerund-participial clauses as integrated post head dependents where the interpretation of the subject is not the head noun.
Time

Our days struggling in the wilderness are at an end.
Let me tell you about his years working in that business.

Experience / Ability

His experience doing this kind of work will come in handy.
He was impressed by her skills manipulating clay.
His background working with children was left out.

Work

His work leading Microsoft's server and tools division helped boost
its profitability.
My career studying and writing about tech has now spanned more than
two decades.
My role working for the state has prompted a resurgence of abuse and
harassment.

For time, the reduced relative analysis is clearly possible, though it usually produces awkward results if substituted with a finite relative clause. For the others however, there is no possible argument for a reduced relative clause as there is no element in the -ing clause that could be understood through the head noun.

Our days struggling in the wilderness are at an end.
(us) struggling in the wilderness (for these days)
?Our days when we were struggling in the wilderness are at an end.
His experience doing this kind of work will come in handy.
(him) doing this kind of work (???)

But then, if we did want to imagine a type of 'deleted' element, why assume it is a relative clause? Why not assume that it is in fact a preposition that has been omitted? That would work in all the cases.

Our days of struggling in the wilderness are at an end.
Let me tell you about his years of working in that business.
His experience in doing this kind of work will come in handy.
He was impressed by her skills in manipulating clay.
His background in working with children was left out.
His work in leading Microsoft's server and tools division helped
boost its profitability.
My career in studying and writing about tech has now spanned more
than two decades.
My role in working for the state has prompted a resurgence of
abuse and harassment.

The simplest solution usually being best, CGEL seems to have gotten it right in categorizing these broadly into post-head modifiers and not putting any special label beyond that on them.

Very balanced. Does one ever come across definitive proofs that a proposed deletion has taken place diachronically? (Feel free to treat as rhetorical rather than spend hours in research.) // Playing devil's advocate, 'Our days struggling in the wilderness are at an end.' might be suggested to be a deleted form of 'Our days that were/we spent struggling in the wilderness are at an end.'

Let me tell you about my time that working in the US. is not grammatical in English.

@Lambie Indeed, which is what the asterisk at the beginning of that sentence indicates.

But the other one though marked incorrect is not incorrect. This: *Let me tell you about my time when working in the US. is fine.

@Lambie Not if you read my time when working in the US as a single noun phrase. Though when does license -ing clauses when heading an adjunct (modifier or supplement) in clause structure, it cannot do this in a noun phrase. Another example: *After that, he deemed my time when working for him wasted. I've tried, but failed to find despite my best efforts, an example in a reputable publication where the when... is clearly a post-head dependent in a noun phrase and has a -ing clause as complement.

Let me tell you about me //when working in the US. I guess our readings are different.
